# How to assign value to array in backing bean JSF 2.0

Tags: arrays, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I have this new problem.  I have the following code in JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 2.2.1:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cmbRole8" value="#{myWorkflow.posToInsert[7]}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a position..." itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{appPositions.allPositions}" var="ap"
     itemLabel="#{ap.roDescription}" itemValue="#{ap.roPositionid}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is repeated 7 more times for a total of 8 selectOneMenu controls where I need to get user input.  Obviously this doesn't work because the getters and setters don't know which index to use when assigning the values.  How can I achieve this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Obviously this doesn't work because the getters and setters don't know which index to use when assigning the values.*

This is not true. Your problem is probably caused because you didn't preinitialize the array yourself. JSF/EL namely won't do it for you (like as with every other "nested object"). It will only set the array value by the given index.

E.g.

```
private int[] positions;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    positions = new int[3]; // You need to preinitialize it yourself!
}

public int[] getPositions() {
    return positions;
}

// No setter needed!
```

with

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.positions[0]}" ... />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.positions[1]}" ... />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.positions[2]}" ... />
```

Comment: Hmm that's a good point.  I had it preinitialized in the declaration but not in the constructor.  I will try it like you said and let you know.  Thank you.

Comment: That wouldn't make the difference. Your concrete problem is thus caused by something else. An SSCCE would help a lot in nailing it down.

Comment: Hmm OK, you're welcome :) Sure that the problem wasn't actually caused by something else? A wrong array length maybe? What exception did you initially got? `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? If so, then it was definitely that.

Comment: How to do the same thing with 2D arrays? Like #{bean.positions[1][0]} ?